# Two random variables uncorrelated to a third. And their product?

Tags: measure-theory, random-variables, correlation, independence

If I have a random variable X that is uncorrelated with another random variable Z, and a r.v. Y that is also uncorrelated with Z, does it follow that the product XY is uncorrelated with Z?

And what if X and Y were not only uncorrelated but independent of Z?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X,Y = \left.\begin{cases} 1 & \text{with probability }1/2, \\ 0 & \text{with probability 1/2,} \end{cases} \right\}$ and further suppose $X,Y$ are independent.  Let $$Z = (X+Y\bmod 2).$$  Then $X$ and $Z$ are independent, and $Y$ and $Z$ are independent, although $X,Y,Z$ are **not** independent.  Now notice that
$$
\operatorname{cov}(XY, Z) = \frac{-1} 8 \ne 0.
$$
Whether this answers you concern about independence is perhaps not clear, since, although $Z$ is independent of $X$ and also independent of $Y$, $Z$ is not independent of the pair $(X,Y)$.  If $Z$ were independent of the pair $(X,Y)$, then $Z$ would be independent of every function of $(X,Y)$, including $XY$.

However, $Z$ is uncorrelated with the pair $(X,Y)$, since correlation, unlike indpendence, is inherently pairwise.  You have pairwise independence of $X,Y,Z$ without independence, but the three are uncorrelated.

Comment: Thank you both Michael and @RobertIsrael for your answers, which I think I understand. But are they not in contrast on one point? Robert is saying that if X and Y are each independent of Z, then any measurable function of them will also be independent of Z. Michael instead says, if I understand correctly, that I need independence of the PAIR (X,Y) from Z to make sure any function of X and Y is independent of Z - and the separate independence X from Z and Y from Z is not sufficient. Have I understood correctly? So who is right? Or are both compatible?

Comment: @ZBrutti : My example shows you which one of those is right. $\qquad$

Comment: Ok I think I now understand your example. Especially the last paragraph seems particularly useful (and novel) to me! Thanks a lot.